# sealed keyword prevents inheritance of a class

Tags: c#, oop, sealed, sealed-class

sealed keyword prevents inheritance of a class. Inheritance is one of the feature of object oriented program. Does it mean sealed is not oops concept?

Comment: Just because a tenant of OOP is inheritance does not mean that _everything_ has to be inherited

Comment: Well if you consider that the keyword `sealed` is entirely dependent on inheritance, I would say that it very much IS an OOP concept. `sealed` wouldn't exist as a concept without OOP.

Comment: thank you maccettura and Matthew

Answer (score -1):

You are right, sealed is a **language construct** and not related to oop.